# Entity FrameWork Many to Many relationship using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables. One called Artist, One called Song and one called Album.

Artist is linked to song as 1 to many. Artist is also linked to Album as 1 to many. Song is linked to Album as many to many so a bridge table was automatically created. The song table has a navigation property of artist and album and the album has a navigation property of Artist and song. I want to add a new song. When adding a song the bridge table doesn't get updated so I want to know how I can reference the album that is associated with the song when adding it.

```
public int CreateNewSong(String name,String songTitle)
{
    using(var context = new Myentities())
    {
        Song theNewSong = new Song()
        Artist refer = context.Artists.Single(o => o.ArtistName == name);
        theNewSong.SongTitle = songTitle;
        theNewSong.Artist_ArtistID = refer.ArtistID;
        context.Songs.AddObject(theNewSong);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return theNewSong.SongID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to remove Asp.Net from your title since this is purely Entity Framework related.

Comment: ...and post your model - what are you using code first?

Comment: I would like to post my model but I don't have enough reputation points to post an image so I tried to explain it.

Comment: post your image somewhere else and add a link

Answer (score 2):

First if you have many-to-many relation between `Song` and `Album` your `Song` entity should contain collection of `Albums` and the `Album` entity should contain collection of `Songs`:

```
public class Song
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to map them. For example if you use Fluent API add this to your context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Song>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Albums)
                .WithMany(a => a.Songs)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("SongID");
                    m.MapRightKey("AlbumID");
                    m.ToTable("SongAlbums");
                });
        }
```

So your method will be similar to this one:

```
public int CreateNewSong(String name, String songTitle, String album)
{
    using(var context = new Myentities())
    {
        Album album = context.Albums.Single(o => o.AlbumName == album);
        Artist refer = context.Artists.Single(o => o.ArtistName == name);
        Song theNewSong = new Song {
                                      SongTitle = songTitle,
                                      Artist = refer                                        
                                   };

        theNewSong.Albums.Add(album);     
        context.Songs.AddObject(theNewSong);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return theNewSong.SongID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you have a 1 to many relationship between song and album so you have to define which album is associated with the song (as you put artist)

```
public int CreateNewSong(String name,String songTitle,String album)
{
    using(var context = new Myentities())
    {
        Song theNewSong = new Song()
        Artist refer = context.Artists.Single(o => o.ArtistName == name);

        Album album = context.Albums.Single(o => o.AlbumName == album);

        theNewSong.SongTitle = songTitle;

        theNewSong.Artist_ArtistID = refer.ArtistID;
        theNewSong.Album_AlbumID = album.AlbumID;
        context.Songs.AddObject(theNewSong);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return theNewSong.SongID;
    }
}
```

I think this may work

Answer (score 0):

Very good answer `algreat`, let my highlight 2 points because I've been stucked with an error of EF Many - to - Many relantionship (the corresponding navigation property was sending and exception and not retrieving the information) and it's important:

- The Mapping in the `OnCreatingModel`, if you don't map to the corresponding intermediate table, EF cannot find this `object` to perform the join, is the table that's omitted in the `edmx` file.
- If you are using the tools for generate the entities and the data context, wich is my case, and modify the `edmx` file you'll probably have to code this again because all this "generated objects" will refresh to the initial state and your mapping, your data annotations and that stuff will be erased.

Hope this helps!